# How can I add in condition for formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I add in one more condition in the formula for Column D that the number range should also see based on the Type.

For example,

- if it's type A, number range is 886000 - 886018,
- if it's type B, number range is 886020 - 886077, and
- if it's type C, number range is 886079 - 886091.

[image]

Column B is

`=IF(AND(A2+1<>A3,A2-1<>A1),"start-end",IF(A2+1<>A3,"end",IF(A2-1<>A1,"start","...")))`

Column D is

`=IF(AND(OR(B2="start",B2="start-end")),A2,C1)`

Column E is 
    `=IF(B2="start",INDEX(A2:$A$1048576,MATCH("end",B2:$B$1048576,0)),IF(B2="start-end",D2,E1))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it needs to be so complicated. Why don't you add a `VLOOKUP`?

```
Column G | Column H
886000   | 886000-886019
886020   | 886020-886078
886079   | 886079-886091
```

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$G$2:$H$4,2,TRUE)
```

Comment: how abt the condition for type?